# Java eclipse converted my files to another encoding. How undo this?

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse asked me if I want read a text file with UTF-8 and I agreed. Then all my files in the project where converted into this encoding. How to undo this or convert all files into Cp-1250 ?

When I click on the file I event don't have option to convert it into Cp-1250:

[image: properities of file]

Comment: Eclipse itself does not convert files. The field you show in the screenshot only concern the display-encoding. The change of the display-encoding does not modify the file!

Comment: Have you checked the Resource property page for the project (right click on the project and open its Properties dialog)?

Answer (score 0):

The drop-down values in the encoding combo only show the most common values. You can type in other values in the text area (the highlighted 'UTF-8' in your image).

The value you type must be something supported by the Java `Charset` class. `Charset` uses the name `windows-1250` for that code page rather than 'CP-1250'

This setting does not actually convert the files, it only changes the way Eclipse reads the file.

You can also set a default for the Workspace in the Preferences on the 'General > Workspace' page.